# form _self removes global variable

Tags: symfony, twig

```
{% set admin = true %}

{% extends admin ? "AcmeAdminBundle::admin.html.twig" : "AcmeUserBundle::user.html.twig" %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

//custom stuff

<form action="{{ path('process_form')}}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
//...whatever
</form>
```

It looks like `{% form_theme form _self %}` removes global variables as I get the following error:
"`Variable "admin" does not exist`"

What should I do to extend the template properly in that case...?

Comment: The [`form_theme`](https://github.com/symfony/TwigBridge/blob/master/Node/FormThemeNode.php) node should do no such thing. You may have found an bug, please open a ticket on github.

Comment: Many thanks @Maerlyn I opened a ticket in twig repo.

Comment: That's not where it belongs. The form_theme node is defined in symfony's twig bridge, which is only a subtree split of symfony. You should open your ticket against the main symfony repository, [this one](https://github.com/symfony/symfony).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a current bug in Symfony. A [ticket](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5284) has been opened.

Answer (score -1):

From the symfony [book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html):

- If you use {% extends %} in a template, it must be the first tag in that template.

Since this is not the case in your code sample you get the error you mention.